# Manipulating a specific list

Tags: list-manipulation

How can the following list

```
list = {{0.1,{l->1,n->2}},{0.12,{l->1.1,n->2.1}},{0.5,{l->0.8,n->9}}};
```

be first organized as

```
list = {{0.1,1,2},{0.12,1.1,2.1},{0.5,0.8,9}};
```

and then remove points that are close (by metric distance), such that the result will be

```
list = {{0.1,1,2},{0.5,0.8,9}};
```

Comment: `list[[All, 2]] = Values@list[[All, 2]];Partition[Flatten@list, 3]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following with your definition of `list`:

```
flattened = MapAt[Apply[Sequence]@*Values, list, {All, 2}]

(* Out: {{0.1, 1, 2}, {0.12, 1.1, 2.1}, {0.5, 0.8, 9}} *)
```

Then remove "close" values; adjust the rounding threshold to suit:

```
filtered = DeleteDuplicatesBy[flattened, Round[Norm[#], 1] &]

(* Out: {{0.1, 1, 2}, {0.5, 0.8, 9}} *)
```